# Laravel - Eloquent relations and variables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many, isnull

I have 2 tables , connected by 'company_name' through `$this->hasMany` method.

```
table 'Companies' -> 'company_name', 'logo', 'description';
table 'Branches' -> 'company_name, 'type', address', 'phone';
```

So in my view, I display the info from the first table, AND if the company has branches, I display them too. Everything works alright until there.  My problem arrives with the 'type' column.

@If the type of the company is for instance '1' , I display a certain text.

So the thing is that if a company has no branches, the view gives an error (Trying to get property 'type' of non-object)...

I have researched but I really don't know how to solve it.

This is in my controller method:

```
$company = Company::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$branch = $company->branch->first();

return view('companies.show', compact('company', 'branch'));
```

I know that I should declare `$branch` only if that company exists on the table 'branches', but don't know really how to. Thanks in advance if someone gives me a hand with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check in the view if the variable is an object before attempting to access its properties. In your case, `$branch` can either be an object or `NULL`.

You can print its value using the following expression:

```
{{ isset($branch) ? $branch->type : '' }}
```

Alternatively, you can use a more concise version of the same expression using the null coalescing operator:

```
{{ $branch->type ?? '' }}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip ;) I have used @if (isset($branch)) and nested my other if's inside and got what I wanted